# SQL multiple joins and replacing values from distinct queries

Tags: sql, firebird

I'll preface this by saying I don't get involved in SQL at all really. We have an internal piece of hardware that stores tests in a Firebird SQL database. The organisation is somewhat confusing, but I've just about got it figured.

I'm assuming the best way to access the information I require is using joins, however, I have a feeling that it might be slightly complicated.

Results Table:

| testID | runID | resultID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1 | 3 |
| 1002 | 7 | 4 |
| 1003 | 55 | 9 |

Records Table:

| testID | runID | resultID | recordedValue | startConnectionIndex | startPointID | endConnectionIndex | endPointID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1 | 3 | value1 | 0 | p-5 | 1 | p-1 |
| 1001 | 1 | 3 | value2 | 1 | p-6 | 1 | p-2 |

Connection Table:

| testID | connectionIndex | connectionID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 0 | con-0 |
| 1001 | 1 | con-1 |

Point Table:

| testID | pointID | connectionID | pointName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | p-1 | con-1 | Point A |
| 1001 | p-2 | con-1 | Point B |
| 1001 | p-5 | con-0 | Point C |
| 1001 | p-6 | con-1 | Point D |

I want to get the records for a particular testID which I seemed to have worked out with:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM RESULTS r
JOIN RECORDS re on ((r.testID  = re.testID) 
AND (r.runID = re.runID)
AND (r.resultID = re.resultID))
```

At the same time, I would like to "replace" the `startPointID` and the `endPointID` with their associated `pointName`. To do so, I need to look up the `startConnectionIndex`/`endConnectionIndex` on the Connection table where the `testID` is equal to `r.testID`. This gives me `connectionID` which I then need to use, alongside `r.startPointID`/`r.endPointID` as well as `r.restID` (again) to find the `pointName` from the Point table.

So the final data should be similar to:

| testID | runID | resultID | recordedValue | ... | endPointID | endPointName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1 | 3 | value1 | ... | p-1 | Point A |
| 1001 | 1 | 3 | value2 | ... | p-2 | Point B |

Comment: Are there some redundant foreign keys? Why does every table have `testID` in it?

Comment: @Barmar - it seems that the way the database is designed is so that for each unique test type the same connection and point can have different pointNames. So the same pointID and connectionID for different tests can be reused on the hardware side of things, but be called different things on the software side of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join with `Connection` and `Point` twice, once for `startPointID` and the second for `endPointID`.

```
select r.*, re.*, p1.pointName AS startPointName, p2.pointName AS endPointName
FROM RESULTS r
JOIN RECORDS re on ((r.testID  = re.testID) 
    AND (r.runID = re.runID)
    AND (r.resultID = re.resultID))
JOIN Connection AS c1 ON c1.testID = r.testID AND c1.connectionIndex = re.startConnectionIndex
JOIN Point AS p1 ON p1.connectionID = c1.connectionID AND p1.pointID = re.startPointID AND p1.testID = r.testID
JOIN Connection AS c2 ON c2.testID = r.testID AND c2.connectionIndex = re.endConnectionIndex
JOIN Point AS p2 ON p2.connectionID = c2.connectionID AND p2.pointID = re.endPointID AND p2.testID = r.testID
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not so good at SQL either, but maybe this could work at least to replicate the table that you have put in the question:

```sql
SELECT rec.testID,rec.runID,rec.resultID, rec.recordedValue, rec.endPointID, p.pointName
FROM RECORDS_TABLE AS rec
JOIN Point_table AS p
ON rec.testID = p.testID
WHERE rec.endPointID = p.pointID
```